# Django view returning stale data, fixed after server restart

Tags: django, database, postgresql, orm

I have a Django webserver with a postgresql database.

I have a view (Django REST framework) that is giving exhibiting strange behavior.

The view lists the date of the most recent record in a table. Records are consistently added multiple times per minute to this table. I do not have any caching implemented on this view.

Today I have observed the following:

- view on production server was returning stale data (latest data 2 days ago)
- view on local development server (connects to same remote database) returned fresh data
- view within `./manage.py shell` run on production server returned fresh data
- I had not restarted production server since 2 days ago
- After restarting production server today, data in view is fresh again
- 30 minutes later, the data is now 30 minutes stale

What could be causing this? Why did I have to refresh the connection to the database to get fresh data?

Relevant code:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_data(self,
            start_date=timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=24),
            end_date=timezone.now()):
        latest_data = self.data.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date).latest('date')
        return {
            'latest': latest_data.date
        }


class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='data')


# views.py
class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()


# serializers.py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.DictField(source="get_data")

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('data',)
```

The method `get_data` is returning stale data when called within the views serializer from gunicorn workers. The data is stale to the date the workers were started.

The `get_data` method does not return stale data when called from a new worker process, or a new shell instance.

Comment: You have a query at module or class level somewhere. But since you have *not posted any code*, we have no way of helping you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I will certainly update my question with code. Based on my observations, this seemed to me to be a database connection issue rather than code itself, as the query was returning expected results on other instances of the server. Also, "we have no way of helping you" is a bit rude. Sure, you could not help me with the information provided but that does not mean others cannot. Also, although I did not provide code, I did provide many symptoms that could point readers to a possible cause.

Comment: But I've told you exactly what the problem is. I just need the code to point out where.

Comment: @DanielRoseman code has been added. That last comment cracked me up. So you have both "told me exactly what the problem is" and "have no way of helping me." Seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: What is `self.data`? Where is that getting set?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is the backwards relation created by Django from a `MyModel` instance to the related `MyOtherModel` instances. By default it would be `myothermodel_set` but I have overrode that name to `data` with the `related_name` parameter

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please let me know how I can improve upon this question. Otherwise, remove the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue. I am fetching data for a timerange, and that time range is being set in the default parameters of the method.

**The default parameters in Python are evaluated once at method declaration.**

I needed to change:

```
def get_data(self,
        start_date=timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=24),
        end_date=timezone.now()):
    latest_data = self.data.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date).latest('date')
    return {
        'latest': latest_data.date
    }
```

To:

```
def get_data(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    if start_date is None:
        start_date = timezone.now()-timedelta(hours=24)
    if end_date is None:
        end_date = timezone.now()

    latest_data = self.data.filter(date__gte=start_date, date__lte=end_date).latest('date')
    return {
        'latest': latest_data.date
    }
```